# Yacc - Building data structures using %union and linked-list

Tags: c, linked-list, bison, yacc

I am trying to build special data structures in my program while using `yacc`.Here is part of my grammar:

```
commands      : commands command    {if($$ == 0){$$ = &$2;}
                                     struct Command* ptr = $$;
                                     while(ptr->next != 0){ ptr=ptr->next;} ptr->next = &$2;
                                     }
                  |                  {$$= 0;}
                  ;

command       : identifier ASSGNOP expression';'  {$$.id = $1; $$.exp=$3; $$.next = 0; }
              | IF condition THEN commands ENDIF  {$$.next = $4;  = $2; $4 = &$$; }
              ;
```

I want my program to create linked list while executing.

```
%type <Command> command
%type <Commands> commands

     //..part in union%{
    struct Command {
        struct Command * next;
        struct Expression exp;
        char*  id;

        struct Condition cond;  
        int licznik;

        }Command;

       struct Command* Commands;         
    }
```

The list should grow by connecting commands together. In the end one pointer to the whole list of structures should be returned. Unfortunately I am having a 'segmentation' fault error. Plus it is iterating forever, never encountering a NULL. I would be grateful for someone pointing me toward what I am doing wrong. When i am deleting ptr=ptr->next; it is working but i dont understand why this is happening. It should point NULL in the end.

Comment: Where are you allocating memory for these commands? Where do you expect this pointers to be pointing to?

Comment: I am not allocating anything. I am using $$ to get to commands. Commands should pointing to list of structure of type COmmand. While executing lexer it should building up.

Comment: And where do you suppose those commands are in memory?

Comment: Does not yacc store this attributes in memory on it own? If not , how it can connect commands at the end.? program       : DECLARE vdeclarations IN commands END

Comment: When executing commands command i can see my previous expression so it is working. THe problem is my ->next never points to 0. And it should!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semantic values `$n` are kept on the parser stack. They do not occupy persistent memory and it is generally an error to take their address. Immediately after the execution of the semantic action, they will be popped from the stack and any pointers to them will become invalid.

If you want to create a linked list of semantic objects, you will need to manually allocate memory, and set the semantic value to the address of the allocated object.

By the way, it is more efficient to build a list backwards, by just pushing each new node at the head of the list, and then reverse the list when complete. That avoids the quadratic scan of the list at each push.